# PHP code to download a csv file from 3rd party website

Tags: javascript, php, csv

Is there a PHP code to automatically download a csv file from a link of a different website? I go to this 3rd party website daily to download list of closing properties in a certain state. The county website offers a link which when you click will download a csv file. I am in the process of building a PHP page where it reads the contents of that csv file into a table but I was thinking maybe there's a way to automate the download as well?

I checked on the link's URL by doing a COPY LINK URL and although the list changes daily, I don't think the download link's URL is also dynamic.

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: Alternatively, http://php.net/curl

Comment: Isn't that for reading a website's contents though? The file download link is something like `http://www.statelistings.com/exportlist.do?doc=4652546&type=csv`. That is what I get when I right click on the word that says "Click here" which is found on their website. When I click "Click here" it downloads a CSV file. Could you guys provide sample code so I can try it? I'm really blank at this and couldn't start something. The sample link url above us just a sample

Comment: You said you found he link's URL by copying he link address, use that with file get contents

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function file_get_contents can fetch a page from a 3rd party server, assuming that the settings are ok in php.ini, so you can get the file by doing this:

```
$contents=file_get_contents=('http://whatever.com/file.csv');
//process $contents here
```

$contents will be a string of the csv file's contents

Comment: I get a `WARNING file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons on line number 3` so I'm guessing it can't be done on that website. A login is required before you can get to that page with that link. The funny thing is even without logging-on I can create a simple <a href> that links to that download link and it dowloads the file immediately without requiring any logins

Comment: I read somewhere that I need to allow file_get_contents on php.ini but is that error being displayed because of my website's php.ini security setting or is it being generated by the website of the url I'm trying to get contents from?

Comment: Its being caused by PHP.ini, almost surely. In your PHP.ini file, on the entry listed allow_url_fopen, change the 0 to a 1, and that should work fine. You will probably need to restart apache after making hat change for it to take effect. Often you cannot change PHP.ini on shared servers. If that's the case, look into using curl instead of file get contents

Comment: I don't have any sample code for doing this in cURL. The link above directs to cURL general guide page :( I can probably just force the user to manually download the file for the mean time but it would have been great if it's automated so they can just click the button and my webpage will auto-download that csv and display it's contents

Comment: Look at the documentation, it explains how to use the cURL API